# C++ std::div doesn't return expected results

Tags: c++

I ran this code on my machine and it output: `11/5 = 2.1` Now I might be crazy but `11/5 = 2.2`

I read into the reference and it says div_t.rem is x%y, which in this case does equal 1, but how can `std::div` be a feature of the language if it doesn't return the expected result of 11/5?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    std::div_t q;
    q = std::div(11, 5);

    std::cout << "11/5 = " << q.quot << '.' << q.rem << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `q.rem` is a remainder from integer division, not the fractional part of the value.

Comment: This is the purpose of `std::div`: not to do the division and give you a floating-point result, but to return the `quot`ient and the `rem`ainder. Otherwise, why make a function that would do division if you've got all sorts of `operator/`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`q.rem` holds the remainder. `11/5 = 2` with a remainder of `1`, there's nothing weird about these results.